# remove items from combobox

Tags: combobox, qooxdoo

i filled the combobox with the following:

```
  for(var x in z)
  {
        var tempItem = new qx.ui.form.ListItem(""+arr[x]);
        tempItem.model=arr[x];
        cbo.add(tempItem);
  }
```

Unfortunately, i didn't find anything, to remove all items from the combobox.

With the following code is this not possible

```
cbo.getList().removeAll();
```

or

```
var childLength = cbo.getList().getChildrenLength();
for (var i = 0; i < childLength; i ++)
{
    var childToRemove = cbo.getList().getFirstChild();
    cbo.getList().remove(childToRemove);
    childToRemove.dispose();
    childToRemove = null;
}
```

Thank you

Mani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet does not work because the cbo does not have any getList()-method. Performing removeAll() directly on the comboBox should do the trick.

Cheers
Andreas